# Sefer on tefilin

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, tefilin

Is there a [sefer](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1429/170) out there that goes through all of the halachos of tefilin, but has pictures to help explain the different parts?

Comment: @AlBerko The connotations are different. Especially when you ruin some of his grammar in the process of fixing his “mistakes.” Voting to roll back to revision 2.

Comment: @DonielF Fix the grammar but what's Sefer has that book doesn't? Showing your sheer knowledge of Hebrew and messing the site? I'm trying hard to standardize the question titles to be useful for search and consistency to make this site useful.

Comment: @AlBerko In my experience a book is used in the sense of a novel, a research book, etc., while a Sefer is used in the sense implied here, on a Halachic, Hashkafic, or otherwise Judaic subject. It’s a noble approach that you take to standardize the word usage, but if you [look here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1857/9682) and the discussions linked there for the old discussion about the parsha tags you’ll see why it was given up on several occasions previously.

Comment: @Doniel the jargon guidelines clearly prefer "book" to "Sefer"

Answer (score 2):

I personally liked very much

- [Inside Stam: An insider reveals the answers to all the questions you should ask when purchasing or maintaining Tefillin, Mezuzos, Megillos, Sifrei Torah and Nevi'im](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1600912133) by R Reuvain Mendlowitz
- [Tefilin and mezuzos](http://a.co/4EPGW2D) by R Yerachmiel Askotzky

Comment: I know R' Mendelowitz personally...expert in the field of stam.

Comment: @chacham more like expert in the industry/market of Stam. There's a lot more to Stam than what is commonly available in the stores and I've heard evidence that he isn't as expert in the rest of it (not to diminish what he does know)

Comment: @DoubleAA Don't believe what they say...He's at Ahavat Shalom tonight between 6:00 and 7:00 pm(Jerusalem time) at the following number: 026255568. Test him, if you like. I enjoy speaking with him. Out of curiosity, have you ordered tefillin according to your learning or relied on the sofer?

Comment: @cha I was recently involved in ordering a full house worth of mezuzot "accd to my learning" for a close family member and found many of the questions I thought worth asking or the opinions I thought worth being machmir for were rarely mentioned in his book, except occasionally without details in footnotes. I've heard another story of a rabbi who knows him and got a thoroughly unsatisfactory answer to his question about a detail of Stm. Not everyone knows the opinions less popular in the modern Charei industry or historical realities of Stm

Comment: @chach if you want to know how 98% of charedim do Stam, his book is great. If you want to know the historical variety of opinions which still exist in the 2% then look further than his book. Maybe he's just hiding the information from people to simplify things or to paint the Charedi industry as 100% traditional. I don't know. Whatever.